# How to run command in Laravel kernel after another successful command

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm creating a custom command which will truncate a table every thirty minutes in the console kernel (for development purposes). I want to run another right after the previous command.

P.S: I have an if statement which prevents running these commands on the production server.

```php
$schedule->command('db:seed')->after(function () use ($schedule) : void {
    $schedule->command('my-command:remove-users-from-tables')
        ->everyThirtyMinutes()
        ->environments(['demo', 'local']);
});
```

I expect to run the seeder right after "my-command" runs successfully every thirty minutes. However, in this way, only `db:seed` runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked the source code for [Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Schedule.php) class.

I think when we say:

```
$schedule->command(...);
```

The artisan command will be scheduled, not run straightaway.

So when you write like this:

```
$schedule->command('first-command')->after(function () use ($schedule) {
    $schedule->command('second-command');
});
```

The second command will be registered, not run right after the first command.

So the best approach that I can think of is run the second command inside the first command according to [this link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#calling-commands-from-other-commands)

You might try something like this:

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class RemoveUsersFromTable extends Command
{
    public function handle()
    {
        // Do something to remove users from table.

        $this->call('db:seed');
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you @Kevin-Bui, but I try this before, in this case, my command runs every thirty minute but seeder not run

Comment: I have check Laravel source code and update my answer accordingly @MohamadKarimi, pls let me know if the new one works.

Comment: Yeeeeees @Kevin-Bui, thanks for the guide ,it works hundred percent.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run B after A you need to schedule A and AFTER that run B:

```
$schedule->command('my-command:remove-users-from-tables')
        ->everyThirtyMinutes()
        ->after(function() {
            $this->artisan->call('db:seed');
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative that may be relevant in some cases (but I can imagine would also be a bad idea in others) is to run `shell_exec`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

If you want to chain two artisan commands together as you would on the cli using `&&` you can simply `shell_exec('php artisan command:first && php artisan command:second')`.

`shell_exec` returns the console output so if your commands print anything (ie, via `$this->info`) then you can print that to console like so: `$this->info(shell_exec('php artisan command:first && php artisan command:second'))`

I'm probably going to get a lot of hate for this answer...